# How to convert an entire folder of BMP images to PPM in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, imaging, medical

```html
from PIL import Image 
import glob, os
directory = "your path "
for infile in glob.glob("*.bmp"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.save(file + ".ppm", "PPM")
```

I was able to convert only one image, can you please help to get entire image converted to ppm format

Comment: You don't need any code or Python, just use **ImageMagick** in Terminal `magick mogrify -format ppm *.bmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me, so long as I was in the directory of interest. Your code does not use the `directory` information, so if you are in a different directory, this likely will not find any `.ppm` files with `glob`, and so be a no-op. I would modify your code as follows:

```py
from PIL import Image 
import glob, os
target_directory = "/path/to/folder"
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(target_directory, "*.bmp")):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.save(file + ".ppm", "PPM")
```